# I m not able to run a postman collection using newman

Tags: api, postman, newman

I m trying to run a postman collection using newman. This collection works fine with postman. However when i run it through newman i see this below error

#  failure        detail

1. Error          Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "IP:
                  10.10.XXX.XXX is not in the cert's list: "
                  at request
                  inside "Translate Dataa"

I have to use newman for my test beacause the script have file post in the request.

A help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out had to appended -k and it worked
C:\Users\anaik>newman run C:\ProgramData\anaik\Postman\app-5.4.1\Test.postman_co
llection.json -k

Comment: "-k, --insecure  Disable strict ssl"